# Can you move applications to arbitrary sound output devices on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have 2 apps that make sound and my PC is connected to a TV via HDMI.
I want one of the apps to output sound to the PC speakers and the other to the TV speakers.

How can I do that please?